# PHP PSR validator

Tags: php, psr-0, psr-2, psr-1

I am looking for a tool that can check my PHP codes and automatically update into as per PSR standard or atleast point out the places where code violates PSR standards. Google search was not too helpful. Is there a tool that can do it ?

Comment: By asking for an off-site resource your question is probably [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For PSR-0, PSR-1 and PSR-2 use [the PHP coding standard fixer](http://cs.sensiolabs.org/)
Install it via composer:

```
./composer.phar global require fabpot/php-cs-fixer
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to look at [PHP_CodeSniffer](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer).